# How to trap Excel macro's error message via Powershell?

Tags: excel, vba, powershell

I'm invoking Excel macro via Powershell like this.

PowerShell script:

```bsh
try {
  $excel.Run("my-file.xlsm!ThisWorkbook.raiseError")
} catch {
  throw $_
}
```

Excel macro:

```vb
Public Sub raiseError()
  Call Err.Raise(1, "raiseError", "I want this message to be trapped!")
End Sub
```

And I get this message:

```
+         $excel.Run("my-file.xlsm!ThisWorkbook.raiseError")
+         ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
    + CategoryInfo          : OperationStopped: (:) [], COMException
    + FullyQualifiedErrorId : System.Runtime.InteropServices.COMException
```

Furthermore, I also want to trap a message raised by macro, `"I want this message to be trapped!"` in this example. I investigated all `$_`'s properties but I couldn't find such message. Is it possible to do that?

Comment: Catching an exception and then throwing it again right away without doing anything else doesn't make any sense. How would you determine whether or not the exception is caught in the first place? Remove the `throw` to check that. If the exception isn't caught add `$ErrorActionPreference = 'Stop'` before the `Run()` statement. Check the `InnerException` property to explore nested exceptions.

Comment: The reason that I use `throw` in catch clause is just I want to throw error without stopping whole process. I added `$ErrorActionPreference = 'Stop'` and using PowerShell ISE I set break point at `throw` statement then process stops there before throwing error.

Unfortunately `$_.Exception.InnerException` returns nothing. In my understanding `$ErrorActionPreference = 'Stop'` is for catching error caused by comandlet, so it's not suitable in this case.